# Is it possible to submit an appended form via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, append, mustache

I'm building an app to manage tables. I'm using mustache templates so that when I need to send some data, the form renders with the necessary data and then it makes the request.
I'll try to explain a little bit more.

This is where I render the form, it works now

```
function renderForm(selector, args){
                $.get('includes/tables/form.mustache', function(template) {

                    var rendered = Mustache.render(template, args);
                    $(selector).append(rendered);
                });
            }
```

The thing is, after the append I try to submit the form as usual ($form.submit() ) but that part is not working. I understand that the element is not part of the loaded DOM and that is why the selector doesn't work. My question is if there's a way to get it to submit the form I just appended. I know I can use ajax to send the data but I actually need it to post and make the page load.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

This is the function that triggers the template render:

```
        $('.main').on('click', '.save-absolute', function(){

            var update_id = $(this).attr('data-update');
            var args =  {
                            'id' : 'update_row_form',
                            'method' : 'POST',
                            'action' : document.URL,
                            'method_force' : 'put',
                            'values' : []
                        };

            $('.table_cell_input').each( function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                args.values.push({'name' : value, 'value' : value});
            });
            args.values.push({'name' : 'update_id', 'value' : update_id});

            // Renders and submits the form
            renderForm('.main', args);

            //NOT SUBMITTING
            $('#update_row_form').submit();
        });
```

And the first function above is the one that renders the template, the thing is the template renders okay, I can see it in the code. But the .submit() part is just not doing anything

Comment: After you append it, it is part of the loaded DOM. You should be able to submit it. Can you show the whole code?

Comment: `$(rendered).submit()` inside the callback, assuming it's a form ?

Comment: I edited my question, it's hard to put all the code since it's a large app, but I hope I made myself clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your code this function

```
renderForm('.main', args);
```

uses `$.get` which is asynchronous. This means that the code following it

```
$('#update_row_form').submit();
```

is running before the ajax call that gets your template has completed and appended your rendered template.

You could allow your renderForm function to accept a third argument which is a callback function to run after the template is rendered. You can then choose to do anything you like after the form is appended.

Something like

```
function renderForm(selector, args, callback) {
    $.get('includes/tables/form.mustache', function(template) {
        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, args);
        $(selector).append(rendered);
        if ( typeof callback === "function" ) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Would allow you to use

```
renderForm('.main', args, function() {
    // anything you like here
    $('#update_row_form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it was generated dynamically the form will not be submitted using normal lookup selector `$(#formId).submit()`

Instead you should find the element from DOM and submit it :

```
$(document).find("form#form1").submit();
```

Or you could take reference from other static content to find the form.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr8cR/)

Comment: I don't see how looking from document is any different.

Comment: It doesn't. It finds the element, it just does nothing on submit